# Javascript drag and drop over elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a solution in javascript + PHP where I can drag images from right panel i.e. **Available colors** to the left image, where I can drag the selected image over left image **(BA3)** the left and it can get fit into the selected part only like **A, B, C** to the left image **(BA3)
I can drag the image from available colors, but not aware of what to be done to get images fit to A, B, C. 
[image: reference image what i want to accomplish]**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have already tried etc. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: I am new to javascript don't understand where to start with

Comment: PHP is server-side and won't help with this apart from maybe storing and serving the colors. Have you tried anything so far? Coloring BA3 is trivial once a color is placed, the only "hard" part is to make the color boxes draggable and have the boxes in the center react to the `ondragend` event. If you don't know where to start, you need to do a lot more research. Break down the problem into parts and solve them individually, or hire somebody to do it for you. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: No, I don't understand where to start with. Evaluating https://interactjs.io/ library hope it may help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API . P.S. You seem to maybe be describing a more specific issue within the scope of dragging and dropping - about exactly where items can be dropped? Is that right? Your description is a little unclear, to be honest. But if you have some existing code, please show it, then at least we have a starting point.